# Master login how to access db SQLite of client data in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want solution for after login of master , master has accessbile client data from sqlite db .
How to make sqLite db centralised so that all user accessible data from db?

Comment: what you want ? explain your question in detail

Comment: I don't understand either. What is the *question* ?